# Counting the number of expressions of a given length

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I am not being able to find some paper or book that dwells on this problem ,if you can recommend me anything there would be great.

I will first state the general problem and some subproblems that I have solved. And that the questions I could not solve that are for me interesting.

**Problem:** How many expression are there of a given lenght ,more exactly having a total number of symbols S that can be subdivided in a set of operations O and a set of terminals T, how many total valid expressions are possible of size n?

For instances with the set $O = \{+,-,/,* \}$ , and $T = \{a,b\}$ and $S = T \bigcup O$ a valid expressions of size 5 (in prefix notation) can be [+-aba] that translates to $(a-b)+a $, this represents an expression of lenghth 5. Let's represents the set of all expressions with this lenght and this operations and this terminals: $EXP_{O,T}^5$. And generically $EXP_{O,T}^n$ is the set of all the operations with a lenght n.

**Subproblem 1**: For instance considering only operations that have as input 2 terms and as output 1 term (binary operators), and calling that set $O_2$, considering that an expressions is in prefix notation after some dwelling some considerations can be made:

**Assert 1:** The number of operators in a expression is equal to the number of terminals +1. (can be proven by strong induction)

**Assert 2:** There are not  expressions with an even dimension (can be proven by strong induction)

**Assert 3:** In evaluating a valid expression , the evaluation ends when the number of terminals counted is equal to the number o operators +1. (it is basically a consequence of 1)

**Conclusion:** this allow us to relate this problem to the Catalan numbers , and it is made obviously by comparing it to the number of possible valid parenthesis expressions. (substituting every terminal by ")" and every operator by "(" )

[+-a+bcd] -> [(()()) )] so the number of valid expressions of size n are equal to the number of (n-1)/2 pairs of parenthesis sequences.

So in the end the number of expressions with only operators with two inputs, and a given lenght lets called it  $ \#EXP_{O_2}^n $ is for n odd equal to:

$$  \#EXP^n_{T,O_2} = Cat(\frac{n-1}{2})\#T^{(n+1)/2}\#O_2^{(n-1)/2} $$

$$\#EXP^n_{T,O_2} = \frac{2}{n+1}\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}\#T^{(n+1)/2}\#O_2^{(n-1)/2} $$

A cool inside on this expression is that for a given value of symbols, #S = P, the value that maximizes the dimension of this space is when  $\#T = \#O2+1 $

**Subproblem 2:** How to generalize this taking into acount unary operations? Lets's call this set $O_1$, one possible case can be $O_1 = \{sin,cos,tan,exp\}$. This subproblem I have solved in the following way. Given a expression of type $\#EXP^i_{T,O_2}$ with $i<=n$ we can form expressions of the type $\#EXP^n_{T,O_2,O_1}$ adding to the rest of the not occupied $n-i$ places unitary operators. This becomes compreensible in the following image
[image]
this example is for n=7 and in this case i= 5, we are creating an $O_1$ expression of dimension 7 from one of dimension 5 of $O_2$. having this image in consideration and noting the following things.

**Assert 1** the last element of an expression cant be an unitary operator

**Assert 2** we are not counting any expression twice if we now add the new expressions build for an i, with the other i's. that is because the number of operators $O_1$ is diffferent

**Conclusion** the expression can be done by this formula
$$ \#EXP^n_{T,O_2,O_1} = \sum^n_{i=1}\#EXP^i_{T,O_2}\binom{n-1}{i-1}\#O_1^{n-i} $$

notes: I could not simply this expression or find an assymtotic limit, i only could compare it with the previous one plotting it.

**Interest problems I didn't solve and that can be fun and are the focus of the question**

**Problem 1** How to generalize this for ternary operators (quaternary operators, n-ary operators)

**Problem 2** How to count and exclude redundancys, being more specific when using some terminals and operations for instance $ O_2 = \{+,-,*,\} $ and $T = \{a,b,1,0\}$ , how to count redundant operations like (1)$A-A$ (2)$1*A = A$ (3)$A+0=A$ (4)$A/1=A$, etc how to count this redundancys and exclude them.Or one more complex redundancy as A+B+C = B+C+A etc...

**Problem 3** In GP ,genetic programming, an interesting field is Dimensional Aware GP, in this type of definition if a variable A represents meters and B represents Time it is not valid to add them or subtract them. This can be writen in the following way: (lets assume every variable of the set T is now associated with a vector D that represents is dimension).In this case T = {(t1,d1),(t2,d2)...)}.For example if t2=A, d2 = [1 0] , and t1=B, d1= [0 1] A+B is not valid. How to count this effect (can be in the simple case with only two tipes of variables, note that when multiplying things become more diffucult) (A*A has dimension vector [2 0]). If not an exact count a complexity result would be interesting

**Conclusion** if you have insights to solve any of these questions or can give me some literature guidance on what to read (papers books) about the topic would be very cool.

Comment: Very nice. I suggest you read about context-free grammars. The enumeration of the words expressed by the grammar is given by the Chomsky-Schutzemberger enumeration theorem. For the problem of redundancy, you have to create ways to understand symmetry of your words. That is harder. Much harder.